# Fix Regex in R (stringr library)

Tags: r, regex, stringr

So I'm pretty good at regex in general, but this is my first time using it in R (strictly using stringr library). I have the following string where I want to only match for "blue" "red" and/or "green". I also want a separate matching group for each one. When I use this regex on the same test string in rubular (online ruby regex editor), it works exactly the way I want but when I do it in R it generates two matching groups where each one is for blue (even though blue only shows up once in the test string). What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it without having to use a different library?

Code:

```
library(stringr)

text="I like blue red and green"
reg<-"(blue|red|green)"

str_match(text,reg)
```

Output:

```
 [,1]   [,2]  
 [1,] "blue" "blue"
```

Comment: Perhaps using `str_match_all` instead of `str_match`

Comment: That fixed the problem of red and green not being matched, but each color is now showing up twice. I'll add another comment for the exact output

Comment: [[1]]
     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "blue"  "blue" 
[2,] "red"   "red"  
[3,] "green" "green"

Comment: I think you can make it a non capturing group instead `(?:blue|red|green)`  https://ideone.com/RpYHRC

Comment: Since your pattern contains a capture group, the result contains two columns, one for the complete match and one for the capture group. If you don't want the repeated column, you can remove the group parentheses from the pattern. Just remove the parentheses.

Comment: What, exactly, is your expected output here?

Comment: Removing the parentheses actually removed the extra column, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me how you want or expect the output to be structured, but here's an approach that gives you back a named vector with the elements that appear in the string (or `NA` if the element does not appear in the string). It uses `sapply` from base R, so no additional packages required.

```
> sapply(c("blue", "red", "green"), function(color) stringr::str_extract(text, color))
   blue     red   green 
 "blue"   "red" "green"
```